# Looping through 2 arrays and retrieve the values from the first array if the id matches with the second array. (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I've been trying to figure out how I would be able to loop through two arrays and match values from each array which should only return the value that matches of the first array.

Array 1:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [contact] => 68
        [field] => 11
        [value] => DBSA
        [cdate] => 2019-11-14T11:21:08-06:00
        [udate] => 2021-03-30T07:54:00-05:00
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [contact] => 68
        [field] => 131
        [value] => ABC
        [cdate] => 2019-11-22T08:34:03-06:00
        [udate] => 2021-03-30T07:54:00-05:00
    )
```

Array 2:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [source] => analysis_utm_source
        [id] => 131
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [source] => analysis_utm_medium
        [destination] => UTM medium
        [id] => 132
    )
```

So in this example I would like to retrieve the values from the first array but only where id/field = 131

I've tried to work with 'array_intersect' but this doesn't seem to give the right output.

I'd appreciate it if someone would be able to push me in the right direction.

EDIT: I've been able to solve it by using array_filter, final code like so;

```
foreach ($fieldValuesDB as $arr) {
    $options[] = $arr['id'];
}

$result = array_filter($fieldValuesAC, function($v) use ($options) {
    return in_array($v['field'], $options);
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what your desired result is. Do you want a filtered array? If so, which one? Do you want a new array that only holds specific values? Do you want to print the values?

Comment: Sorry, I will print out the desired result in any future questions. I've only included; 'So in this example I would like to retrieve the values from the first array but only where id/field = 131'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
foreach($array2 as $k => $v)
{
    $key = array_search($v['id'], array_column($array1, 'field'));  
    if($key){
        echo print_r($array1[$key]);
    }
}
```

you will get the index of the element in your first array stored in $key variable

Comment: It's rather inefficient to call `array_column` inside the loop, since it will always give the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've eventually used array_filter like so;
`foreach ($fieldValuesDB as $arr) {
 $options[] = $arr['acid'];
}

$result = array_filter($fieldValuesAC, function($v) use ($options) {
 return in_array($v['field'], $options);
});`